# How to install gcc-4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, gcc, rvm

I am trying to update ruby and rails on my system (osx 10.8.2)

When I run

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=gcc-4.2
```

I get the following error:

```
You requested building with 'gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path.
```

2 questions; how do I install using gcc-4.2 (I have installed command line tools in xcode)?
Also, How do I get it to the correct path?

Any help in this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using Homebrew already, you'll probably want to install it, along with the apple-gcc42 package. This script will do that for you, but you'll probably just want to manually run the parts of it that you want: https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop/blob/master/mac

Comment: I do have homebrew installed, how do I run the script?

Comment: In that case, you should just be able to run the GNU Compiler section: `brew tap homebrew/dupes` && `brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42`

Comment: ~ marty$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
Error: Already tapped!
 ~ marty$ brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
Error: autoconf-2.69 already installed
Error: automake-1.13.1 already installed
Error: apple-gcc42-4.2.1-5666.3 already installed

Comment: Hm, gcc-4.2 should be in your path after that. If you just run `gcc-4.2`, does it work?

Comment: ~ marty$ gcc-4.2
-bash: gcc-4.2: command not found
 ~ marty$ rvm gcc-4.2
Unknown ruby interpreter version: '4.2'.

Comment: Can you try to find gcc-4.2 on your system? Maybe it's in /usr/local/bin?

Comment: I have found it, but instead of an exec icon, it is a blank doc icon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25526/discussion-between-martymcfly-and-ari)

Answer (score 0):

Try  installing using this package:  https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: @noli I was able to get gcc4.2 installed, but how do I add it to the path?